# Swift type inference and basic addition

Tags: swift

Pretty new to Swift and learning about data types.

```
 let partNumber = 3.2
 let wholeNumber = 2
 partNumber + wholeNumber //Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Double' and 'Int'
 3.2 + 2 // outputs 5.2
```

I understand that `partNumber` is a `Double` type and `wholeNumber` is an `Int`. What I don't understand is why playground errors out when I attempt to add both constants together. To add confusion the addition works when not assigned as a constant.

Comment: I'm not a Swift guy, but I would assume the compiler doesn't not allow implicit type casting (because Swift is a strongly-typed language). When you run `3.2 + 2` out of context, the compiler can infer the type of those literals in that particular expression (i.e. it's not bound by any previous declarations). It can't do the same here `partNumber + wholeNumber`, because type inference has happened at assignment time.

Comment: If you are still on Xcode 9.4.1 you can use Sourcery to make a template and generate all the Overloads on the Plus-Operator if thats your thing. I don‘t think its worth it though. Thinking about what the output type would be etc would be necessary, which is currently avoided by you having to make decisions instead of the compiler playing guessing-games.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The + operator does not support adding a Double and and Integer together in this way

If you change up your code to make sure wholeNumber is a Double type, then it'll work

```
let partNumber = 3.2
let wholeNumber: Double = 2
let result = partNumber + wholeNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all covered in the Swift book under [Numeric Type Conversion](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID324).

Some relevant quotes from the subsection titled "Integer and Floating-Point Conversion":

> Conversions between integer and floating-point numeric types must be made explicit

This is followed by an example similar to your code. Your code needs a cast:

```
let partNumber = 3.2
let wholeNumber = 2
partNumber + Double(wholeNumber)
```

and:

> The rules for combining numeric constants and variables are different from the rules for numeric literals. The literal value 3 can be added directly to the literal value 0.14159, because number literals don’t have an explicit type in and of themselves. Their type is inferred only at the point that they’re evaluated by the compiler.

Which covers the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

> To add confusion the addition works when not assigned as a constant.

That doesn't "add to the confusion" at all. It's the *answer*. There is implicit coercion between numeric types for literals (what you call a "constant") but not for variables. It's as simple as that.