# How to understand the Int Double conversion in Swift 5.5?

Tags: swift, type-conversion

Extend the example in “The Swift Programming Language” (Swift 5.5) “Integer and Floating-Point Conversion”:

```
3 + 0.14 // allowed

let three = 3
let rest = 0.14

3 + rest // allowed
0.14 + three // compile error
three + 0.14 // compile error
```

I don’t understand why the last two lines are taken as compile error. Can anyone help to explain a bit? Thanks.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/51407773/1187415

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic rules:

- A numeric literal without type annotation can be converted implicitly *if possible*.
- A constant or variable is initialized with a fixed type which cannot change. A floating point literal becomes `Double` and an integer literal becomes `Int`.

So `three` is `Int` and `0.14` is `Double`.

`3 + rest` works because `3` can be inferred as Double.
But `0.14` cannot be inferred as `Int` so the last two lines fail to compile.

Comment: What is "e fixed type" supposed to be?  'the fixed type'?

Comment: I'm just offering you a rare, free typo fix service so that others can understand what Rule #2 means.